# How to prevent a folder deletion, while leaving full control permission on all its content on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, file-management

Honestly, I'm a little disappointed this is so hard and isn't intuitive to do, because it seems a trivial task. I want to prevent a folder from being inadvertently deleted by myself, but not files and subfolders inside. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Remove the the `delete` [_show advanced permissions_] ACL from your user for the folder only (right-click folder → _Properties_ → _Security_ → _Advanced_). Test to determine if that's the only ACL to remove, as `modify` may be needed, however I think that would prevent you from writing to the root of the directory.

Comment: @JW0914, just unchecking "delete" for a user in advanced permissions doesn't help

Comment: Then try others, referring to [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc732880(v=ws.10)) for how the ACLs function. **Note:** You should have two listings for your user for that directory's ACLs - the first should only apply to _This folder only_ with basic permissions `Read & execute`, `List folder contents`, `Read`, and `Write` selected _(`Modify` and `Delete` [Advanced Permissions] should not be selected)_  and the second should have permissions for _Subfolders and files only_. If this works, I'll create an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to create an explicit deny ACE for the folder telling Windows a user or group cannot delete the folder itself.

`Right-click` the folder → `Properties` → `Security` → `Advanced` then click `Add`. In the Permission Entry window for your folder, click `Select a principal`.

Next, in the Select User and Group window, in the text box, enter the user's name (yours in this case) and press `ENTER`.

Change type to `Deny` and select `Show advanced permissions`, click `Clear All`, then check `Delete`.

Now click `Ok` in the Permissions Entry window, then click `Ok` again in the Advanced Security window, before finally click `Ok` one last time in the folder properties window.

Now `right-click` the folder → `Delete`. A popup should appear telling you you cannot delete the folder without modifying the permissions.

Note, however, the only disadvantage to this is that you cannot open the folder in File Explorer without agreeing to modifying the permissions. You can beforehand create the subfolders inside of it before you do this or you can access and create the file and folders through the command line if they do not exist yet.

Comment: There's a better way to go about this, as the removal of all ACLs, except `Delete`, creates more problems than it solves... please see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1610930/how-to-prevent-a-folder-deletion-while-leaving-full-control-permission-on-all-i#comment2456460_1610930) comment for the correct ACLs and relevant [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc732880(v=ws.10)) for ACLs. _(Please use correct markdown for ordered lists, e.g. `1.`, `2.`, etc.; please reference the formatting toolbar)_